# "BoxConstraints forces an infinite height" when rendered inside GoRouter ShellRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I know there are a lot of these errors on the Internet, but this one made me curious. I created a very simple design (MRE) to demonstrate it.

This issue seem to happen when I use the [Shell Router](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html) from [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) to route child widgets. The design runs smoothly when I run it myself.

To demonstrate it, let me start by sharing some of the boilerplate code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      MaterialApp.router(title: "Flutter Demo", routerConfig: router);
}
```

My super simple design with a `BaseWidget`, that will be shared among a few widgets, and a `BodyWidget` with a big height:

```dart
class BaseWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const BaseWidget({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(children: [
      const FlutterLogo(size: 80),
      child,
    ]));
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const BodyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(100, (index) {
        return Text(
          "Any text ${index + 1}",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

If I just configure everything directly I don't have any problems. But when I use `Shell Route` to configure my `BaseWidget` to be shared across my routes, the configuration no longer works.

To demonstrate that I'll be sharing the last piece of code containing the router with two routes: the first can be accessed through the `Direct` button. This one works without any problem. The second uses `Shell Route` and will throw some errors:

```dart
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: "/",
      builder: (context, state) => BaseWidget(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go("/full"),
              child: const Text("Direct"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go("/shell"),
              child: const Text("Using Shell"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: "/full",
      builder: (context, state) {
        return const BaseWidget(child: BodyWidget());
      },
    ),
    ShellRoute(
        builder: (context, state, child) {
          return BaseWidget(child: child);
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: "/shell",
            builder: (context, state) => const BodyWidget(),
          )
        ])
  ],
);
```

The errors shown are listed below:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Assertion failed: file:///.../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart:833:12
constraints.biggest.isFinite is not true
The relevant error-causing widget was: ListView

Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: box.dart:2009
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:550
Another exception was thrown: Unexpected null value.
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: mouse_tracker.dart:205
Error: Unexpected null value.
```

So my question is, why does this work when I configure it directly but not work when I use `Shell Route`? Is it some bug with the library or am I missing something? Any tips to solve this problem?

Tested on:

```
Flutter 3.7.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4b12645012 (2 days ago) • 2023-04-03 17:46:48 -0700
Engine • revision ec975089ac
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1
go_router: ^6.5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keys example :

```dart
static final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
static final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

...

```dart
 static final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
      initialLocation: '/login',
      navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          redirect: (context, state) => '/login',
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'login',
          path: '/login',
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return CustomFadeTransition(
              child: const LoginPage(),
            );
          },
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              name: 'signup',
              path: 'signup',
              pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return CustomFadeTransition(
                  child: const SignupPage(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ShellRoute(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state, child) {
            return CustomFadeTransition(
              child: MinMultiProvider(
                controllers: [
                  MinService.permanentController(
                    DashController(),
                  ),
                ],
                child: DashPage(child: child),
              ),
            );
          },
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
                parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
                ...
```

You can added root navigator key in your sheel router if your scope can return, in my  case i not return in pages the of _rootNavigatorKey, in this case is logoff, but can use like this

```dart
        ShellRoute(
          rootNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey, //makes it possible a return  a the rootNavigator scope
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state, child) {
```